# binding to list of nested objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding

as I'm not sure how binding to nested objects works let me explain my predicament:

Here is my class:

```
public class DeliveryContactViewModel
    {        
        public List<DeliveryContact> Contacts;        
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeliveryContact
    {

        public string ContactType { get; set; }
        public string ContactAddress { get; set; }
        public List<bool> Reasons { get; set; }
    }
```

OK, so nothing extra special here...

Let's tackle View part now:

My idea was to make a form (pseudocode following)

```
<form action="/path/to/action" id="frm-contact" method="post">
    <input id="someID" name="Name" type="text" />
    <fieldset>
       <select name="i'm_not_sure_what_to_put_here">
           <option value="someValue1">someValue1</option>
           <option value="someValue2">someValue2</option>
       </select>
       <input id="someID" name="ContactAddress_but_i_want_it_in_the_First_DeliveryContact" type="text" />
      <input type="checkbox" value="Reason1"  name="again_not_sure"/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Reason2"  name="again_not_sure"/>
      <input type="checkbox" value="Reason3"  name="again_not_sure"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

//and the idea is to make as many of these fieldsets as i would need "Contacts" (that go into List of "DeliveryContact"

As you can see from the pseudocode I'm not sure what to name my HTML elements in order to successfully bind it to a model.

And finally the controller part how do I go about signing it. Will this be enough? Will the naming convention in View be enough to match everything into my controller that looks like this.

```
public ActionResult DeliveryContact(DeliveryContactViewModel model)
{
     foreach(var item in model.Contacts)
     {    
        //something
      }
}
```

Cheers,
T.

Comment: I believe you have to generate the input name values yourself. Something like `model.Contacts[0].ContactType` and `model.Contacts[0].Reasons[0]`. This means you would also have to introduce an index of some sort.

Comment: Yeah, later last night I've figured it out. That was in fact it, adding indexes to html element names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like merekel suggested the trick was to add indexes to html element names:

Example:

```
<select name="Contacts[1].ContactType">
           <option value="someValue1">someValue1</option>
           <option value="someValue2">someValue2</option>
</select>
```

or like this for another level of nesting

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true"  name="Contacts[1].Reasons[2]"/>
```

Ofcourse indexes are dynamic.

I got the basic idea from Scott Hanselman... [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)

Cheers,
T.