# Get table of RadioButtons in ASP MVC 4 as Dictionary (not for RadioButtonList)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form that needs to be posted to server without use of JavaScript. To do this, I submit the form and have a Model created to parse the necessary parameters.

One of the things I have is a table of RadioButtons.

That is, I have a table with several rows, and in each row a number of columns with a radiobutton. Each row's radiobuttons belong to the same list, i.e., you can choose one option in each row, but more than in one row (example: you can choose Radiobutton 2 in Row 1 and RB 3 in Row 2, but not RB2 in Row 1 and RB3 in Row 1 -you CAN, though, leave rows without any RB checked-).

Is there any data structure I can use to let my Model parse this table of radiobuttons? I find that I can't use RadioButtonFor and the name of the property, because then all the radiobuttons would belong to the same list (and I would be able to choose only ONE option overall). I don't know how to let the program know that they should belong to the same property, because as far as I understand, MVC parses each form element through that attribute.

Thanks.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14843132/binding-to-list-of-nested-objects) and others on the same topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a `Dictionary<int, List<SelectListItem>>`. The dictionary's int key would be the row number and the List would be the options for each radio button group.

I use a "RadioButtonListFor" helper to turn collections of SelectListItems into radio button groups (code below). In your View, you will have a modification of this code to put in the table cells around the individual radio buttons. You could add a parameter for a wrapping HTML block to this function perhaps:

```
// jonlanceley.blogspot.com/2011/06/mvc3-radiobuttonlist-helper.html
        public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues)
        {
            var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<span class='RadioButtonListFor'> ");

            if (listOfValues != null)
            {
                // Create a radio button for each item in the list
                foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
                {
                    // Generate an id to be given to the radio button field
                    var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);

                    // Create and populate a radio button using the existing html helpers

                    var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    htmlAttributes.Add("id", id);

                    if (item.Selected)
                        htmlAttributes.Add("checked", "checked");

                    var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, htmlAttributes);


                    // Create the html string that will be returned to the client
                    // e.g. <label<input data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an option" id="TestRadio_1" name="TestRadio" type="radio" value="1" />Line1</label>
                    sb.AppendFormat("<label>{0} {1}</label> ", radio, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));
                }
            }

            sb.Append(" </span>");
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
        }
```